# Bi-coloring JavaFX TableCell Background?

Tags: css, javafx

I have a `javafx.scene.control.TableView` containing some `javafx.scene.control.TableColumn`s containing some `javafx.scene.control.TextField`s. Some of the `TextFields` should get a bi-coloured background: diagonally divided, the upper left half one colour, the lower right half another colour. Like the cells for Ge, Sb, Po in https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodensystem#/media/Datei:Periodensystem_deutsch_-_neue_Farben.svg. Is this possible without a background image?

Edit: added some code. For simplicity’s sake, i omitted the surrounding table and use now a `javafx.scene.text.Text` instead of a `javafx.scene.control.TextField`. The basic setup that follows gives a uniform background to the `StackPane` which is a start.

```
public class DividedBackgroundDemo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    primaryStage.setTitle("Test: Diagonally divided colour background");

    Text txt = new Text("Text");
    txt.setFont(Font.font("Arial", FontWeight.BOLD, FontPosture.REGULAR, 50));

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(txt);
    root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;");

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 200, 200));
    primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
    }

}
```

Later on, when i will use a 13x13 grid of `Text`, i will have to imbed each `Text` into it’s own `StackPane` or another (perhaps more appropriate) subclass of `Region` to be able to provide an individually coloured background for each `Text`. And some of those `Text`s (especially the one in this example) should have a bi-colour background, both colours divided by the line from left bottom to right upper corner.

The simple solution would be to provide a background image. It’s not too difficult to produce one. But then, i have to produce a new background image for every pair of colours. I would prefer a more flexible solution.

All property setters and CSS properties i have found provide a one-colour-background. But sometimes i require bi-colour.

The proposed `LineGradient` would be acceptable if everything else fails. I would prefer a clear border between both colours, not a gradient.

Comment: what is the problem, exactly? what have you tried and how is the outcome different from what you expected?

Comment: Hmm .. in code, you can use a path: have pathElements that surround the triangle, fill it with the alternate color and bind the x/y of the elements to the text bounds as appropriate. Most probably not the most elegant method, but working ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i found a solution, at least for the simplified problem. Thanks to @kleopatra. As a path, i used a `javafx.scene.shape.Polygon and filled it with the appropriate colour. Using a`StackPane`, it is important to watch the z coordinate. Background naturally bottom, filled polyline as first content in the pane, and text on top.

```
public class DividedBackgroundDemo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Test: Diagonally divided colour background");

        Text txt = new Text("Text");
        txt.setFont(Font.font("Arial", FontWeight.BOLD, FontPosture.REGULAR, 50));

        Polygon triangle = new Polygon();
        triangle.getPoints().addAll(new Double[] { 0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 0.0, 0.0, 200.0 });
        triangle.setFill(Color.YELLOW);

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(triangle);
        root.getChildren().add(txt);
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;");

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 200, 200));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```